# recive webserver type using get_headers in php

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array with the name of `$urls` that contain some urls

i want to receive webserver of each one

but when i using get_headers my output will be :

```
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.0 200 OK
    [Date] => Mon, 24 Feb 2014 01:38:18 GMT
    [Expires] => -1
    [Cache-Control] => private, max-age=0
    [Content-Type] => text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
    [Set-Cookie] => Array
        (
            [0] => xxx
            [1] => xxx
        )

    [P3P] => CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
    [Server] => gws
    [X-XSS-Protection] => 1; mode=block
    [X-Frame-Options] => SAMEORIGIN
)
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [Connection] => close
    [Date] => Mon, 24 Feb 2014 01:40:57 GMT
    [Server] => Microsoft-IIS/6.0
    [X-Powered-By] => ASP.NET
    [X-AspNet-Version] => 2.0.50727
    [Set-Cookie] => xxx
    [Cache-Control] => private
    [Content-Type] => text/html; charset=utf-8
    [Content-Length] => 65230
)
```

so i need to have each `[Server]` in to array

i need to have an array like this

```
[0] => gws [1] => Microsoft-IIS/6.0
```

here is my php code :

```
$urls = array("http://google.com","http://ping.com");
foreach ( $urls as $key ) {
// do something

}
```

i don't insert codes in `foreach` loop because i write them wrong

i don't know how can i move keys value from an array and copy it into another array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the array value into another array while looping through them. Like so:

```
$urls = array("http://google.com","http://ping.com");
$servers = array();
foreach ( $urls as $key ) {
    $header = get_headers($key, 1);
    if(isset($header['Server'])) {
        $servers[] = $header['Server'];
    }
    // Do stuffs...
}
```

It's best to check if the ['Server'] value exists before we try to push it into our array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$urls = array("http://google.com","http://ping.com"); 
$serverlist = array();

foreach ( $urls as $key ) {

     $site_headers = get_headers($key,1);
     if(array_key_exists("Server", $site_headers)) $serverlist[] = $site_headers["Server"];
}

var_dump($serverlist);
```

You can see the response (live) at http://codepad.viper-7.com/nRle4F